# como integro 2 modulos de spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Quiero integrar 2 proyectos que estan totalmente separados pero que trabajan en cooperacion, y quiero unirlos en un solo proyecto, usan multimodulo de MAVEN

> que debo fijarme? las dependencias? las librerias?

**clase principal del primero proyecto**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.circuitbreaker.EnableCircuitBreaker;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.EnableFeignClients;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@Import({
        com.goo.common.notifications.messaging.producer.Application.class
})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**clase principal del segundo proyecto**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class Application {

    public static void main(String args[])  {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: segundo proyecto consideramos que es  un submodulo verdad? cual es el nombre de tu paquete del proyecto?

Comment: @Jorgesys los 2 estan en modulos separados, para el ejemplo lo llamares por modulo A y modulo B

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar Spring Integration para que se comuniquen entre si evitando dependencias, eso hace que haya bajo acoplamiento un principio importante en la POO.

Consiste en declarar un gateway en la clase que invoca los servicios de otro modulo:

```
<int:gateway id="gatewayId"
            service-interface="package.nameGateway"
            default-request-channel="requestChannel"
            default-reply-channel="replyChannel" 
            default-reply-timeout="10000">
            <int:method name="method" payload-expression="#args[0]">
                <int:header name="argument1" expression="#args[0]" />
            </int:method>
</int:gateway>

<int:channel id="requestChannel" />

<int:channel id="replyChannel" />
```

Service activator, declarado en el modulo que escucha la peticion:

```
<int:service-activator send-timeout="5000" id="saId" 
            input-channel="requestChannel"
            expression="@nameInterfaceImpl.method(headers.argument1)">
</int:service-activator>

<int:channel id="requestChannel" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Agrega  :

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages="<paquete>")
@EntityScan(basePackages="<paquete>")
```

esto sería el cambio en tu clase principal:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages="<paquete>")
@EntityScan(basePackages="<paquete>")
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@Import({
        com.goo.common.notifications.messaging.producer.Application.class
})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```